# Send props to react component from redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React component in which i'm making a redirect

```
return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/questions',
        state: { open: true }
        }}/>;
```

I need to access this state in the questions component, and i'm trying so with `this.state.location.open` which returns undefined. Am i missing some import statement, or am i just completly wrong?

Comment: I think the state of the component can be accessed, when the component is to be mounted. In this case, you may not be able to access the state

Comment: I might have explained it wrong. I need to pass some state from the first component to the component that i redirect to. And non of them are child components to each other, but two different routes

Comment: okay, posted on answer from what I know, hope it helps

Comment: @Fripo ... I am stuck in the same situation ... have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you try sending some params (may not be the best solution)

```
return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/questions/data_to_send',

        }}/>;
```

While receiving in the questions route, you can try this in index.html (of questions route)

```
{
      path: 'questions/:data_to_receive',<---- HERE 
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        System.import('./containers/QuestionsComponent').then((m) => {
          cb(null, m.default)
        })
      }
}
```

and again in Questions Component, the data can be received as props in QuestionsComponent as,

```
this.props.routeParams.data_to_send
```